# Running sdbinst on a .sdb in a network share location

Tags: command-line, windows-xp, network-share

I want to run the sdbinst command on a .sdb database file as well as open it in the compatibility administrator. I have no problem doing this locally when the .sdb is stored on the machine i'm using, but i'd like to be able to open and run sdbinst on it when the file is stored in a network store location.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to the MS Help files within the MS Compatibility Toolkit. 
See: "Mitigating Issues by using Compatibility Fixes". There is an example of a network deployment workflow: "Deploying the Contoso.sdb Database to your environment".
The basic pattern is to place the sdb on a network Share. Create a one line deployment script that references a path to that share.`(sdbinst "\\SomePath\Ex.sdb" -q)` Either push or execute the deployment script to/on each target computer in your environment.